Pattern to objects for entire fill in Inkscape
I have a seamless pattern I'm using as a fill for a path (Inkscape 1.4). I've got the pattern scaling tuned just right to tile my path pleasingly. Now I'd like to turn the entire filled pattern to paths but "pattern to objects" produces just the paths from a single tile. Is there a way to get all the paths from a filled pattern?
My only alternative seems to be to ignore patterns entirely and use tiled clones then union them together but then I have to prepare a bunch of tiled grids in the sizes I'll need (and I don't get to use the nice, visual pattern scaling/translation).
Btw I need paths because the software in which I'll be using the resulting vector doesn't respect layers or clipping or basically anything besides a single path.

Hi. Can I ask why you need the pattern converted to objects/paths?  Are you using this for something like a cutting machine?  Inskcape doesn't have this functionality as far as I know. Yes, your best bet is probably to ignore patterns altogether, and instead create tiled clones, or even use the Tiling LPE effect to create a repeating pattern. Then use boolean operations or the shape builder tool to cut away the excess, and to make the individual objects.

There's one workaround which looks obvious: Print the shapes which have pattern fills with a PDF printer. Exporting as PDF is useless, because the original SVG and fill patterns would only be packed into the PDF i.e. nothing would be changed. But a PDF printer very likely could produce something which could be rendered without having Inkscape or other SVG capable program.
I made some tests. Good news at first: The PDF printer didn't generate a bitmap image, the pattern was exploded to separate vector paths.
Unfortunately Inkscape doesn't speak right to PDF printers. The fill pattern or the shape outline or both of them were badly distorted. I tested Adobe PDF, Foxit PDF Printer and Microsoft PDF Printer. Everyone created different distortions. Another possible reason is that I do not have the newest versions, so it's well worth the effort for you to try for example the newest Adobe PDF, if possible.
But even if the PDF printing worked exactly the result would not fulfill your specs. The pattern paths are not sliced along the outline shape edge. The outline is used as a clipping path and you wrote it cannot be accepted.
How to utilize PDF printing if the shape outline is distorted but the pattern is exploded OK?
You can adjust the pattern to good density, scale and rotation in Inkscape. Print as PDF a big strokeless rectangle filled with that pattern. Open the PDF in Inkscape by using the internal import option. The pattern is changed to separate paths. You can use it in the same way as tiled clones i.e. you very likely must convert strokes to paths and combine the shapes before you can cut the pattern with an outline shape.
The only thing you gain with PDF printing is the possibility to use the node tool and the pattern fill adjustment handles to adjust visually the pattern layout to fit into the shape. But that's not a meaningless benefit.
Your problem is not new. I have seen suggestions of exporting as PNG or creating  directly in Inkscape a high resolution bitmap copy. That bitmap image can be traced back to vector. The result can well be usable if the bitmap image resolution is high enough. I tested it. The result was on the screen identical with the original if the bitmap image was 600 pixels per inch. Zooming in say 400%, of course, lifted up the inaccuracy.
Sorry for text  only answer. I have no "attach image" button due the low reputation.

I have no better idea and I'd juste give you an advice :

I'd do pattern to object then inspect the result *
use tiling LPE with split elements enabled and a very light gap X and Y inset (for example -0.001 mm) : this inset avoids issue when uniting tiles. Then I'd flatten LPE (or do path > object to path), select all "tiles" and do path > union).
Then I'd use boolean ops (intersection) to achieve the same visual aspect as a clip.

*This works fine when pattern has a simple structure (a unique path with no stroke, for example). You may have to work on pattern to simplify it). When pattern consists in multiple paths of different colors, you may repeat the process for each path).
